# Bin Sensor that tells when something has been placed in it

Tags: sensor

I’m planning a bin project, essentially before anything can be placed in a bin, it has to be scanned. Any suggestions on a sensor that can be placed inside the bin that will ensure that the scanned item has been placed and bin and nothing other than the scanned item has been placed in the bin.Preferably more environment sensing than machine vision.

Comment: If it's a serious application Have a look at RFID Siemens, Sick, ...many others.

Comment: Another thing you could consider other than RFID/NFC (Which is probably the most sensible answer to your problem) is just a weight sensor. Weigh the item before placing in the bin, then weigh the added weight of the bin? The question needs a bit more context before we can seriously suggest answer. How big are the items? what is the purpose of this system? will it have main power or battery? The question has a lot of unknowns.

Comment: If you could weigh the bin that might work (and the items have to be heavy enough to register a meaningful difference.) Self-checkout systems work this way, but they also often fail. Otherwise, machine vision is your huckleberry, and given that you only want empty or not-empty it’s a really simple recognition task.

Comment: What's the nature of the objects that will be placed in the bin?